# How to calculate the closeness of a set of numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, measure-theory

Given a set of numbers, I would like to have a measure of how close they are to each other. I would like the calculated measure produces a single value. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to subtract the minimum from the maximum, to give the range.  Does this work for you?

Comment: I thought to start with this. However, by proceeding in this way from a set of `N` numbers, I will get `N` values. But I would like to get a single value. However, if I consider the values obtained as a vector in `N` dimensions, I could calculate its distance from the origin... What do you think about this?

Comment: No, you get one value.  The maximum is the greatest of the numbers, the minimum the least.  Their difference is one number.  Yes, you can calculate the magnitude of the vector, but that does not get the idea of closeness.  $\{1,1.1\}$ and $\{1,-1.1\}$ give the same magnitude, but that does not seem to be what you want.  Similarly, $\{100,101\}$ would give a much larger magnitude than $\{1,2\}$